# Need generic utility C# method for populating ASP.NET DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method like the following in a utility class.  I would like to change the parameter dataSource to accept any type of data source, that is, DataSet, DataView, List<T>, DataTable, and ArrayList.

Is this possible? How would I change the method signature (and parameters and types) to allow me the flexibility of passing in any acceptable datasource for binding?

```
public void FillCombo(DropDownList ddl, DataTable dataSource, string textField, string valueField, bool addSelect) {
    ddl.DataValueField = valueField;
    ddl.DataTextField = textField;
    ddl.DataSource = dataSource;
    ddl.DataBind();
    if (addSelect) 
        AddSelectCombo(ddl, "Select", -1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following is what you're looking for.

```
public void FillCombo<TSource>(DropDownList ddl, TSource dataSource, string textField, string valueField, bool addSelect) {

    ddl.DataValueField = valueField;
    ddl.DataTextField = textField;
    ddl.DataSource = dataSource;
    ddl.DataBind();

    if (addSelect) AddSelectCombo(ddl, "Select", -1);

}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using generics in this case? Yes, David asked for them, but I suppose he could write this code himself easily. And it doesn't give him any benefits over accepting an object.

Comment: I think I read too far into the word "generic" in the title of the question. I think I managed to make a generic solution into a solution with generics :) Either way, it works.

Comment: @Adam: whoops, I also thought that David asked for generics, but after reading your comment I returned to it and found that probably I was wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: You could also clear the items of the dropdown before data-bind

Answer (score 8):

Well, since the `DataSource` property on a `DropDownList` has type `object` you could change your method signature to accept an `object`. That would not make your method generic (in the .NET sense), but maybe it would be enough anyway.

Comment: +1. Since there is no common interface for all datasources which could be used as a constraint for generics, there is no advantage of using generics in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar in my library, and what I did is create it as an Extension method (.NET 3.5+) on the DropDownList class...

```
Imports WC = System.Web.Controls
```

...

```
<Extension()> Public Sub DataBindEx(
    ByVal target As WC.DropDownList, ByVal DataSource As Object, 
    ByVal DataTextField As String, ByVal DataValueField As String,
    Optional ByVal SetTooltips As Boolean = True
)
    With target
        .DataSource = DataSource
        .DataTextField = DataTextField
        .DataValueField = DataValueField
        .DataBind()
    End With

    If SetTooltips Then
        For Each li As ListItem In target.Items
            li.Attributes("title") = li.Text
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I'll leave it for you to translate to C#.

Comment: Question addresses a different problem.

Comment: Not really. I mentioned the Extension method, but I am showing how I dealt with a similar case where any type of datasource needs to be accepted. Since the .DataSource property of the DropDownList control is of type Object, that is what I wrapped it to in the parameter-list of my function.