# How to avoid repeated code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-reuse

I'm still quite new to programming and I noticed that I'm repeating code:

```
protected void FillTradeSetups()
{
    DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    DataTable dtTradeSetups;

    dtTradeSetups = DB.GetTradeSetups();
    ddlSetups.DataValueField = "tradeSetupId";
    ddlSetups.DataSource = dtTradeSetups;
    ddlSetups.DataBind();
}

protected void FillTimeFrames()
{
    DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    DataTable dtTimeFrames;

    dtTimeFrames = DB.GetTimeFrames();
    ddlTimeFrames.DataValueField = "tfCode";
    ddlTimeFrames.DataSource = dtTimeFrames;
    ddlTimeFrames.DataBind();
} 

protected void FillTradeGrades()
{
    DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    DataTable dtTradeGrades;

    dtTradeGrades = DB.GetTradeGrades();
    ddlTradeGrades.DataValueField = "tradeGrade";
    ddlTradeGrades.DataTextField = "descr";
    ddlTradeGrades.DataSource = dtTradeGrades;
    ddlTradeGrades.DataBind();
}

protected void FillExecutionGrades()
{
    DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    DataTable dtExecutionGrades;

    dtExecutionGrades = DB.GetExecutionGrades();
    ddlExecutionGrades.DataValueField = "executionGrade";
    ddlExecutionGrades.DataTextField = "descr";
    ddlExecutionGrades.DataSource = dtExecutionGrades;
    ddlExecutionGrades.DataBind();
}
```

How can I be a bit smarter about this? Can you help me re-write the code so that it's not repeating so much?

**UPDATE**

Wow, thanks for the replies, I thought I'd post what I'm thinking of implementing. I also created myself another little worker to remove some other ugly duplicated code. What do you think of this?

```
void FillDropDownList(DropDownList ddl, DataTable dt, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, string defValue)
{
    ddl.DataValueField = dataValueField;
    ddl.DataSource = dt;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataTextField))
    {
        ddl.DataTextField = dataTextField;
    }

    ddl.DataBind();
    ddl.SelectedValue = defValue;
}

private string GetTradeItem(DataTable tradeDetails, string attribute)
{
    return tradeDetails.Rows[0][attribute].ToString();
}
```

and then call it with something like:

```
int tradeId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["tradeId"]);
DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
DataTable tradeDetails = DB.GetTrade(tradeId);
FillDropDownList(ddlTradeGrades, DB.GetTradeGrades(), "tradeGrade", "descr", GetTradeItem(tradeDetails, "tradeGrade"));
```

Coding feels great when something ugly turns into something more elegant.

Comment: A good question to ask at an early point in your career. The ability to avoid "snippets" and "copy & paste programming" is an important skill to acquire.

Comment: You want to read [Refactoring](http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need generic utility C# method for populating ASP.NET DropDownList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894646/need-generic-utility-c-method-for-populating-asp-net-dropdownlist)

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate, but great answers should be merged with original.

Comment: Isn't this question about how to avoid repeating code, not about this specific example? I have to say, I'm a bit disappointed by the answers, which are too specific.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Read the OP's question at the bottom of the post.  It's clearly about this specific example for learning purposes.

Comment: @mellamokb Well, it SHOULD be about the more general case, which would be much more interesting and useful, both to questioner and answerers.

Comment: @Neil: I agree, but that's a blog post (or a read of Refactoring), and not a Stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
void SetupDataSource(DropDownList ddl, DataTable dt, string dataValueFieldm, string dataTextField)
{
    if (ddl != null)
    {
        ddl.DataValueField = dataValueField;
        ddl.DataSource = dt;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataTextField)) 
        {
            ddl.DataTextField  = dataTextField;
        }

        ddl.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("ddl");
    }
}
```

Comment: @John to avoid NullReferenceException but I guess the requirement for the check is situational and sometimes it's better not to check.

Comment: @mellamokb I just added `DataTextField`

Comment: @Bala: my point was that the original code didn't have the check, so one presumes it was not required.

Comment: I would argue the null-check there is *bad practice* because it hides a programming error (with an implied contract the values passed in are "valid"). If anything it should be `if (ddl == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ddl");`.

Answer (score 7):

FWIW, perhaps something like:

```
void BindControl(DropDownList ddl, string valueField, string textField, DataTable data) {
    ddl.DataValueField = valueField;
    ddl.DataTextField = textField ?? valueField; // textField can be null
    ddl.DataSource = data;
    ddl.DataBind();
}

DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
BindControl(ddlTradeGrades, "tradeGrade", "descr", DB.GetTradeGrades());
...
```

However, that plumbing isn't terribly duplicated by itself and ease of future modifications/maintenance should be considered.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Create a method that sets the things that you want:

```
void SetValues(DropDownList ddl, string datavalue, string text, object ds)
{
    ddl.DataValueField = dataValue;
    ddl.DataTextField = text;
    ddl.DataSource = ds;
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
SetValues(ddlTradeGrades, "tradeGrade", "descr", dtTradeGrades);
```

Comment: @John: A type. Unfortunately, not a type that's defined in the Framework. Changed to `Object` to match what `DropDownList` uses.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
void FillData(DataTable dataSource, DropDownList ddl, string dataValueField, string dataTextField)
{
    ddl.DataSource = dt;
    ddl.DataValueField = dataValueField;
    ddl.DataTextField = dataTextField;
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
FillData(DB.GetTradeSetups(), ddlSetups, "tradeSetupId", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
   private void BindMyLists()
    {
        DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
        BindDropDownList(this.ddlExecutionGrades, DB.GetExecutionGrades(), "executionGrade", "descr");
        BindDropDownList(this.ddlTradeGrades, DB.GetTradeGrades(), "tradeGrade", "descr");
        //etc
    }
    protected void BindDropDownList(DropDownList dropDownList, DataTable dataTable, string dataValueField, string dataTextField)
    {
        dropDownList.DataValueField = dataValueField;
        dropDownList.DataTextField = dataTextField;
        dropDownList.DataSource = dataTable;
        dropDownList.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: `ddlTradeGrades` -> `dropDownList` in `BindDropDownList`

Comment: Yeaaah... I hit submit way too quickly and had loads of errors.  Down vote deserved :).  Fixed for future reference.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

See [Need generic utility C# method for populating ASP.NET DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894646/need-generic-utility-c-method-for-populating-asp-net-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 1):

May be like this...

```
protected void FillDdl(DropDownList ddl, string dataValueField, Func<DataTable> dataTableMethod)
{
    FillDdl(ddl, dataValueField, null, dataTableMethod);
}

protected void FillDdl(DropDownList ddl, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, Func<DataTable> dataTableMethod)
{
    DataTable dt = dataTableMethod();

    ddl.DataSource = dt;

    ddl.DataValueField = dataValueField;
    ddl.DataTextField = dataTextField ?? dataValueField;

    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

and then call directly like this

```
DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();

FillDdl(ddlSetups, "tradeSetupId", DB.GetTradeSetups);
FillDdl(ddlTimeFrames, "tfCode", DB.GetTimeFrames);
FillDdl(ddlTradeGrades, "tradeGrade", "descr", DB.GetTradeGrades);
FillDdl(ddlExecutionGrades, "executionGrade", "descr", DB.GetExecutionGrades);
```

or you could still have skinny individual methods

```
protected void FillTradeSetups()
{
    DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    FillDdl(ddlSetups, "tradeSetupId", DB.GetTradeSetups);
}

protected void FillTimeFrames()
{
    DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    FillDdl(ddlTimeFrames, "tfCode", DB.GetTimeFrames);
} 

protected void FillTradeGrades()
{
    DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    FillDdl(ddlTradeGrades, "tradeGrade", "descr", DB.GetTradeGrades);
}

protected void FillExecutionGrades()
{
    DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    FillDdl(ddlExecutionGrades, "executionGrade", "descr", DB.GetExecutionGrades);
}
```

Comment: +1 but FYI, using delegates can trigger some obscure CLR bugs related to debugging and unit testing. In this case, the methods being called are so simple that the delegate is not actually required, so I would do it without the delegate. If they were methods with differing signatures, or if more than just the method call was required, then the delegate would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. So would it be better to pass a string methodName in the method and then use reflection (slow and probably overkill) or case statement to call the appropriate method on DBUtil?

Comment: No it would be best simply to take a parameter of type `DataTable` and use `DB.GetTradeSetups()`, `DB.GetTradeGrades()`, etc. in your caller.

Comment: Right, as @mellam: says, you don't need the full generality provided by a delegate or by using the method name.